# WireMock timesout if multiple requests are made simultaneously

Tags: .net, wiremock

I made a request spammer to loadtest my mock and when I run multiple requests in consequence the response time takes longer, which is expected and I made a different request with Postman, the request time times out the response. The server is good enough to handle that load but it times it out. Is there something I can do so it doesn't timeout. For example not use transform in resposnes and make so it caches just for testing purposes?

Comment: What is the performance you are observing and what performance do you expect to see? How many concurrent requests are you sending? Have you tried running a profiler to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: The performance of the cpu was only 60%, and response times went from 500ms on the first request to 1200ms on the 80th request if the requests were concurrent. So I found a configuration option "HandleRequestsSynchronously" and set it to false. Now the 1st requests response time was 500ms and the 80th stayed the same at 500ms and the cpu use is 100%. I will see how well this works. Are there any downsides to doing it async?

Comment: FYI 500ms still sounds like a lot. 50ms would be more typical on reasonable hardware.